# Data types not matching in function call

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameters

I am having trouble matching up data types for a function I have written,

The function is:

```
void generate_all_paths(int size, char *maze[][size], int x, int y) {
   ...
}
```

This parameters size, x, and y are all super simple. I believe it is the maze that is throwing me off. It is intended to be a multidimensional size x size array, containing characters of the alphabet which acts like a maze.

When I try to call the function in main as such:

```
int main() {
    char *exmaze[][6] = { {"#","#","#","#","#","#"},
        {"S","a","#","h","l","n"},
        {"#","b","d","p","#","#"},
        {"#","#","e","#","k","o"},
        {"#","g","f","i","j","#"},
        {"#","#","#","#","#","#"}
    };
    generate_all_paths(6, *exmaze, 1, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

My IDE complains that there is no generate_all_paths function with matching data types for its parameters.

I am fairly certain that my problem is in main where I defined exmaze but my tweaks were unable to fix it.

Does anybody have any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: @CoryKramer Hi, thanks for your response. I tried what you said and changed it to char** and changed exmaze to char** as well.

The call of generate_all_paths in main no longer gave an error, but now the definition of exmaze is causing problems.

The error is “Cannot initialize an array element of type ‘char **’ with an lvalue of type ‘const char [2]’”

Comment: As a sidenote, you're assigning string literals to pointers to **non**-const chars. Such conversion is illegal in c++.

Comment: @user2079303 Hey, thanks for your response. I do apologize for that, I'm quite new to C++. I'm a little confused on how I would go about fixing that. From my understanding (and according to my textbook), a char is any of the ASCII characters. Why is " char ex = "g" " translated as a string literal then?

Comment: You can fix that simply by declaring `exmaze` as `const char *exmaze[][6]` and declaring the parameter of  `generate_all_paths` as `const char *maze[][6]`. Not that I also changed the size of the passed array to be constant because variable sized arrays are not allowed in standard c++.

Comment: `Why is " char ex = "g" " translated as a string literal then?` I don't understand your question. That piece of code does not compile and I don't know what "translated as a string literal" means. You cannot initialize a character variable with a string literal.

Comment: @user2079303 regarding your first comment, I have applied the changes and I'm back to square 1. The IDE is complaining that the parameters do not match up.

The code looks like this now: `void generate_all_paths(int size, const char* maze[][size], int x, int y)`

and `const char *exmaze[][6] = ...`

Comment: Yes, that was an advice beside your current problem. That is why i didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @user2079303 What I'm trying to say is why would `"g"` classify as a string literal? Is that not a char since it's a single ASCII character?

Comment: Double quotes define a string literal regardless of the number of characters the string contains. And in fact, that string literal contains two characters: `'g'` and `'\0'`. All string literals are terminated by the null character.

Comment: @user2079303 Okay that makes sense, I understand now. How would I go about just defining something as a char then? That's what's really confusing me right now. `char ex = g` does not look right

Comment: Indeed, in that code `g` would be an identifier. See my previous comment, single quotes are for character literals. I recommend reading a book about c++ syntax and basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, using a template is the most elegant way for this:

```
template<int size>
void generate_all_paths(const char *maze[][size], int x, int y) {
    ...
}

int main() {
    const char *exmaze[][6] = { {"#","#","#","#","#","#"},
        {"S","a","#","h","l","n"},
        {"#","b","d","p","#","#"},
        {"#","#","e","#","k","o"},
        {"#","g","f","i","j","#"},
        {"#","#","#","#","#","#"}
    };
    generate_all_paths(exmaze, 1, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Please also note the **const** char[][]!

Comment: Thank you!! This was it. I have no idea what a template is so I'll have to read up on it now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

`*exmaze` - why the dereferrence? `generate_all_paths(6, exmaze, 1, 0)` will pass the pointer by value - which is I suppose what you want in this case.
You haven't shown what's `size`, but just make sure it's compile-time known constant.

Also, questions like this almost always get recommendations to use standard containers like `std::vector` so I won't miss it.

Comment: We have had no exposure to vector and have revolved around array for the entire course, so I'm not sure if vector would be the way to go for me. Thank you though.

Comment: @cursayer OK, if it's for learning purposes. Didn't `generate_all_paths(6, exmaze, 1, 0)` work though?

Comment: @LogicStuff `size` appears to be the first parameter of the function and thus not constant.

Comment: @user2079303 Oh, I see. Why did I get upvotes instead of Thomas?

Comment: @LogicStuff Unfortunately no, the comments to my question are how far I've gotten.

Comment: @crusayer Try out the template function then. Unlike function parameters, template parameters are compile-time constants and the code will be valid.

Comment: @LogicStuff I voted yours rather than his because Thomas didn't explain that dereferencing the array variable is wrong nor that the `size` must be compile time constant. Sure, those things are fixed in his code, but explaining is more useful in my opinion. And your vector suggestion is most sensible.